Z index on button and button :after not doing what I think it should do
I have a button that is set to relative and a gradient element positioned absolute that is supposed to sit behind. The element is sitting behind the text of the button and not the actual button. I'm guessing that somehow the after block and the buttons padding and and border are stuck together so the z index is just pushing both of them back but I don't know how to fix it.
I tried

messing with the z index
different position settings
trying some ways to reset the index
I used the z-index to move the after block in front of the text to test if the z-index was doing anything

a Fiddle example
(trying to move the gradient behind the white button.
https://jsfiddle.net/lazer_lad/sL7x5ugy/7/
<button class="primary-button">Learn More</button>

<style>

.primary-button {
  
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 13px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 99%;
  
}
.primary-button::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -100;
  border-radius: inherit;
  
  width: 102%;
  height: 102%;
  background: rgb(138, 179, 252);
 
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(167, 158, 252, 1) 20%,
    rgba(138, 179, 252, 1) 80%
  );
  
  top: 6px;
  left: 4px;
  

}


</style>


is the style  .primary-button::after{top:0;left:0} that you want?

Simply wrap your button in a 'btn' container, then apply the '::after' pseudo-element to this wrapper.


.btn-wrap {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 13px;
}
.primary-button {
  padding: 16px 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: inherit;
  margin-block: 0px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 99%;
  
}
.btn-wrap::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: inherit;
  width: 102%;
  height: 102%;
  background: rgb(138, 179, 252);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(167, 158, 252, 1) 20%,
    rgba(138, 179, 252, 1) 80%
  );
  top: 6px;
  left: 4px;
}
<div class="btn-wrap">
  <button class="primary-button">Learn More</button>
</div>



